# How to copy a sub-directory folder to new directory with a new folder?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to copy a sub-folder to a new directory. This copy should create a new folder and the sub-folder that I copy at a first place will be located in the new folder.

Example.

```
Folder A

  -- sub folder 1

    --Sub folder 1a

    -- Sub folder 1b

  -- Sub folder 2

    --Sub folder 2a

    -- Sub folder 2b
```

I want to copy `sub folder 2`, which will include `sub folder 2a` & `sub folder 2b` to a new directory with a folder name `Folder B`. However, the `folder B` is not exist. How can i do that?

Comment: Create the new directory `Folder B`, then use `rsync` or `cp -R` to copy `Sub folder 2` into it.

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with:

```
mkdir folder-b
cp -r sub-folder-2 folder-b/
```

And if you want a one-line; just put ";" behind the first command and type the second one directly thereafter.

Comment: Oh. I should create a new folder first? What if directly copy the directory along with the folder name? I tired already with the suggested answers you gave. Yeah it works.

Comment: Im thinking if there's another way to copy and create the directory at the same time.

Comment: No need to `mkdir` before copying. Just pay attention to the paths. I suspect that you want the folder-b to be at the same level with folder-a so, assuming you are in their parent directory: `cp -r folder-a/sub-folder-2 folder-b` should suffice.

Comment: well, looks like it cannot copy since there's no folder b director.

Comment: Well, the snippet I gave you does create that directory first. I am not sure what else to tell you. There is a command that tells you how to create a directory.

Comment: ops, my bad. it works anyway, wrong directory just now. Thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

rsync tool will help you do this.

```
rsync -r FolderA/SubFolder2 FolderB/
```